# Excel Copy on certain cells to a new worksheet row if value is not blank

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that will check column E in my xls file and if it is not blank copy the row to a new worksheet. However I can't find how to exclude cells. Columns C, D, E, F, and G and the search columns. If the macro I am running (in this case E) has data in it, I want to copy every cell on the row Except C, D, F, G. Is this possible?

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    J = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("E1:E1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
        If c <> "" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you copy the whole row and then delete the cells that you don't want...?

Comment: Yeah I have been doing that but was trying to consolidate as many steps as I can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can add the delete part in your code:

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    ' Change worksheet designations as needed
    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    j = 1     ' Start copying to row 1 in target sheet
    For Each c In Source.Range("E1:E1000")   ' Do 1000 rows
        If c <> "" Then
           Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
           With Target
              .Range("C" & j).ClearContents
              .Range("D" & j).ClearContents
              .Range("F" & j).ClearContents
              .Range("G" & j).ClearContents
            End With
           j = j + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: That is perfect. Will do exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: one more question. Instead of clearing the contents can I just delete the columns?

Comment: You can do that after copying all the data.

Comment: I did but because I am new it says it was recorded but not displayed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is to write an array of strings which contain the column/rows that you do not want to copy.

Then write an if statement saying that if the current column/row the code is currently looking at then it should move onto the next section.

Here is how to define an array if you didn't know

```
Dim DoNotCopy(1 to 10) as ListRows *OR as ListColumns*
```

There you can define each part of the array as columns/rows

```
Set DoNotCopy as Sheet("blah").Range("D:D")
```

Hope this helps!